# what is the Purpose of Remote webdriver between webdriver interface and chromedriver class

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Search Context is the super most interface in selenium, which is extended by another interface called Web Driver.

-All the abstract methods of Search Context and Web Driver interfaces are implemented in Remote WebDriver class.

-All the browser related classes such as Firefox Driver, Chrome Driver etc., extends the Remote Webdriver class.

As per the above stmt How the remote web driver class can give the definition for all the abstract methods which defined in the search context interface and webdriver interface. because the implementation details are different specific  with browser for the function driver.get/driver.title like that

why can not chromedriver or firefoxdriver class directly extend the webdriver interface. why  remotedriver class kept in between webdriver interface and chromedriver/firefoxdriver/iedriver class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the implementation may be different for each browser at the driver level (`chromedriver.exe`, `geckodriver.exe`, `IEDriverServer.exe`, etc.), the mechanism by which the language bindings execute the commands is the same for all browsers. So, while each browser-specific driver class *could* implement the interface directly, the code in each driver class would be identical. The use of `RemoteWebDriver` as a base class eliminates duplicated code. Additionally, the `RemoteWebDriver` class has the added benefit of being useful to execute WebDriver commands against a browser running on a different (remote) machine from the one where the language binding code is executing.

Moreover, the `SearchContext` interface defines two methods, `findElement` and `findElements`. The `WebDriver` interface isn’t the only one to extend it; `WebElement` does too. It’s perfectly valid to find an element child element of an already-located element. Consider the following example HTML fragment:

```
<div class="foo">
  I don’t want to select this div.
</div>
<div class="bar">
  I need to do something with this div.
  <div class="foo">
    But I also do need to select this div
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.foo"))` would give me the wrong element, the `<div>` I specifically do not want. However, I can do the following to get the proper element:

```
// Assume driver is a valid WebDriver instance
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.bar");

// Since WebElement also extends SearchContext,
// we can do this, which limits the scope of the
// find to only children of the parent element
WebElement child = parent.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.foo");
```

Now I can manipulate the exact element I want.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim for your reply . Could you please explain little bit about the below sentence " It’s perfectly valid to find an element child element of an already-located element. "

Comment: By that, I simply mean that one can call `findElement` on a `WebElement` instance, and the find is restricted to only children if that element. I’ll add an example to my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: HI Jim, can you add an example to make it more clear

Comment: @Sai I’m not entirely sure what other kind of example you want. My answer already includes an example with a sample HTML snippet and associated Selenium code. Can you help me understand what is inadequate about the example already provided?